# Android: System.out: "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap Uri:[B@4072aa78" Prompt when resotre image stream to ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmapimage

I have referred couple of similiar [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) regarding the message prompted from System.

1. The image string is a byte array type Bitmap format. It was encoded to string format by using andorid's Base64 class tool. Then it was saved to mysql DB with Blob format.
2. On my new App, I want reload the Blob image sting to ListView and show the image: I tried two approaches, but all were failed loading image to listview:

   a. put the re-loaded Blob imange(it is a string text type) as value of HashMap's key/value pairs. And then,initial an Adaper (ex. SimpleAdapter) to load the key/vales' and then try to show it on ListView(failed).

   b. Similar a, but use Base64 decode method to decode the Blob image back to byte array first. And take it as Byte array type as value of hashMap's key/vale pair.(failed)

I have had studied this problem couple of days and no progress for this problem. If I used wrong process before, Please guide me to correct it, thanks !

By the way. the stored Blob image string can be re-loaded and display to ImageView using 
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap) method without problem. So, the stored image string data is valid bitmap data.  However, this method can not be used on ListView.

Comment: From your question title, it looks like your not referencing the data in your array but the memory space of the array object itself.

Comment: Thanks Blundell ! I can not figureout what's your concenrs. The "System.out" message is shown by LogCat and it is green. There was not the "Red" or "Orange" color error message shown. is it a android bug ?